# Checking for nested param in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller, I used to be able to say:

```
if params[:business][:branch]
```

After Rails 4, when I try the same I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the only way I can find to do it in a single line now.

```
params.has_key?(:business) ? params[:business].has_key?(:branch_id) : false
```

**Kind of verbose.**

Comment: if you can do it by keycheck only surely it didnt work in rails3 either. if `[:business]` does not exist you cannot get values from it regardless of the rails version.

Comment: This is a real weakness in Ruby in my opinion. There's no nice way to do this. They should take a leaf from Swift's optional syntax book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many possible answers, one of which you proposed in your question.

I really love the [`Hash#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) method. It returns the value associated with a Hash key, and optionally allows you to supply a default to return in case the key is missing. With that, you can make a construct like this:

```
if params.fetch(:business, {}).fetch(:branch, false)
  # do stuff
end
```

This way you don't even need any conditionals or Hash key presence checks in your code.

Comment: This is what everyone should use to safely navigate the nested params.

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of

```
if params[:business][:branch].present?
   ..
end
```

just because it keeps the params[sym] form so it's easier to read.

You can also use `blank?` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F

```
unless params[:one].blank? && params[:two].blank?
```

will return true if its empty or nil

also... that will not work if you are testing boolean values.. since

```
>> false.blank?
=> true
```

in that case you could use

```
unless params[:one].to_s.blank? && params[:two].to_s.blank?
```

Comment: Your example actually doesn't work as intended. If `params` has a key `:business`, the `unless` clause would be executed, regardless of whether the `:branch` key is actually present or not. In my example I tried to avoid this complexity by using `fetch`. It's true that the bracket notation looks more familiar, but in this case sticking to it introduces other complexity instead.

Comment: @fivedigit : Yes I like your trick..infect get to learn new thing.. but here I just show the other way...